# Object doesn’t support this property or method – Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I went through some questions already posted from this error section but I couldn't find a real match. So I'm once again looking for support from the SO community.

I got this error for [bassistance validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) ([docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)).

**CODE**

```
jQuery("#formTest").validate({
            rules: {
                event_title: "required",
                calendar1: "required",          
                calendar2: "required",
                event_venue: "required",
                event_des: "required",
                event_access: "required",
                event_email: {required: true,email: true},
                imagesrc:"required"
            },
            messages: {
                event_title: "Please enter the event title",
                calendar1: "Please select the start date",          
                calendar2: "Please select the end date",
                event_venue: "Please enter the event venue",
                event_des: "Please enter the event description",
                event_access: "Please choose one access option",
                event_email:"Please enter valid email address",
                imagesrc:"Please upload image"
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Which error? Can you post it? Moreover, you could provide a simple example to reproduce the issue. You may post it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the heading of the question that is the error produced by IE

Comment: @Harish This message could mean nearly anything... from a wrong parameter to some jQuery function to a wrong call on one of your own objects. Without further code and/or info, you won't get any answers.

Comment: i have a doubt don't know weather it is a good judgement or not, i have heard IE produces error when a variable is declared in the same name as a form element it produces such an error is this that kind of stuff?

Comment: @mdrg This page includes that plugin and calls this that's all code included as your suggestion i thought of using the plugin but will jsFiddle show any error?

Comment: Have you tried running on Firefox with Firebug enabled? This will show you exactly where the error is occurring and you should be able to inspect the code and variables with it, to ascertain the underlying cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this error is that you are not referencing the jQuery javascript file...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't have the script included, you will get this error for any calls to the jQuery framework.

Comment: Right - it won't be this then! Can you post an example of this somewhere at all (i.e. the HTML and JavaScript) - the snippet you have supplied doesn't give me much to go on.